# Frame with ComboBox not appearing

Tags: java, awt

I would like that when I click on a button it open a *Frame* containing a combo box, but the frame does not appears. I'm using AWT.

```
public class ActionF extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        setBounds(100, 200, 900, 450);

        Choice choice = new Choice();
        choice.addItem("Choice 1");
        choice.addItem("Choice 2");
        choice.addItem("Choice 3");
        add(choice);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the code for the button that opens the frame?

Comment: 2 tips.  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  2) Don't use AWT Components in this millennium.

Comment: And now I actually look at that code snippet - `setLayout (null);`  is going to cause problems.  Learn how to use layouts.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is missing some essential information, e.g. the button that is supposed to open your frame.

A shot in the dark: Could it be possible, that you forgot to add the ActionListener to the actual button instance? This should do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame f = new Frame();
    Button button = new Button();
    ActionF actionF = new ActionF();
    button.addActionListener(actionF);
    f.add(button);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```